# footer does not cover the entirety of the length of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

This is my first time writing in html and css, so sorry if it's confusing and dumb.

I'm trying to make that sticks to the bottom and covers the length of the page, the problem is that i tried everything i could, from padding to width:100% other thant searching online, what can i do?

I'm using angular and i have installed bootstrap, please don't hesitate to ask any question or to ask me to explain myself (i'm not a native speaker), have a nice day and thank you!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 2270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: #e91e63;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.siteFooterBar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgb(207, 207, 207);
  height: 78px;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  background: #F3F3F3;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font: 25px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.foot {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.content img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.content img:hover {
  filter: invert(400%);
  filter: brightness(4);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(-100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
}


/*responsive*/

@media(max-width: 100%) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 100%) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-col">
        <div class="content">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1yvwx9I.png">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Azienda</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PlaceHolder</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Aiuto</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Consegne</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reso</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Informatica privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Seguici su</h4>
        <div class="social-links">
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You sure it's not your `container` class causing the problem? Seeing how it has a max-width.

Comment: try using the "container-fluid" class instead of container

Comment: this question has nothing to do with angular. While you might use bootstrap, it still also has nothing to do with bootstrap. There are no specific bootstrap classes present that are not overwritten by your custom CSS. So in the end it's all custom CSS.

Comment: Length would be the `height` when referring to a web page. Did you mean you want it to cover the `width`?

Comment: yes i meant the width! @Kameron

Comment: i will modify the tags if i can @tacoshy

Comment: i will try it right now and update you thanks @Ownagin

Comment: i already tried removing it @AldinBradaric

Comment: @Ownagin i just tried but nothing happened, it stays the same

Comment: @LorenzoPompei I'm confused about what you mean by getting it the full width. Currently in your snippet it is the full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to align a footer at the bottom of a webpage is just by setting it to `position: relative;`. However, this entails that there is more content that is equal to or greater than the viewport height. Hence, aligning the `footer` after the content and at the bottom.

If you don't have content, use `position: absolute;` on `footer`. Then you can set `bottom: 0px;` to get it at the bottom. Then set `left` and `right` to `0` to get it the full width. See below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 2270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* new */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}


/* end new */

.footer {
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: #e91e63;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.siteFooterBar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgb(207, 207, 207);
  height: 78px;
  color: #9B9B9B;
  background: #F3F3F3;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font: 25px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.foot {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.content img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.content img:hover {
  filter: invert(400%);
  filter: brightness(4);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(-100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
}


/*responsive*/

@media(max-width: 100%) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 100%) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  fooo
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-col">
        <div class="content">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1yvwx9I.png">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Azienda</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PlaceHolder</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Aiuto</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Consegne</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reso</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Informatica privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-col">
        <h4>Seguici su</h4>
        <div class="social-links">
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: it worked! thank you so much, i removed bottom: 0px; because when tryint to put some text it just went over it, but thanks a lot!

Comment: i actually tried to upvote, but says that i need at least 15 rep

Comment: there is a problem with the code, it doesn't get pushed down when i add more content and if i do, it stays in the middle of the page and the text from the page goes "under it"

Comment: @LorenzoPompei Use `position: relative;` then on `<footer>` and put it after all of the other code you added. Should be at the very bottom. `asbolute` is only effective when placing at the bottom when the content doesn't exceed `100vh`.